# Sobrecarga operador+ c++

Tags: c++

Estoy intentando crear una sobrecarga de operador+:

```
Racional Racional::operator+(const Racional& r) {

    Racional resultado;
    resultado.m_numerador = r.m_numerador + m_numerador;

    resultado.m_denominador = r.m_denominador + m_denominador;

    return resultado;
}
```

Y a la hora de hacer la suma me salta un error:

```
void operar(const Racional &r1, const Racional &r2,Racional resultado, char op){
     if(op == '+'){
         resultado = r1 + r2;  //Aquí está el error: Ningún operador "+"coincide con estos operandos. 
}
```

¿El operador+ esta mal hecho?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La operación `r1 + r2` se convierte en `r1.operator+(r2)`. La sobrecarga del operador requiere que `r1` no sea `const` y dicha condición no se cumple, luego no existe una sobrecarga del operador que sea válida.

prueba a dejar la función como `const`:

```
Racional Racional::operator+(const Racional& r) const {
//                                              ^^^^^
```

Comment: Funciona lo que has comentado, pero no entiendo el porqué agregando "const" al final de la función se arregla.

Comment: @Chariot piensa que `r1` es `const`, luego solo podrá invocar métodos `const`. Tu sobrecarga del operador no es `const` y por eso no es válida al ejecutar `r1.operator+(r2)`. Al hacer que el operador sea `const` se soluciona el problema.

Comment: @Chariot hay varias formas de sobrecargar los operadores. Por ejemplo también podrías tener esto: `Racional operator+(Racional const& r1, Racional const& r2)`. En este caso la sobrecarga estaría en una función libre (no es miembro de `Racional`. Eso sí, para que esta versión pueda acceder a variables privadas de `Racional` tendrías que declarar la función como `friend`: `class Racional{ friend Racional operator+(Racional const&, Racional const&)`. Nota que al ser una función libre no puede ser `const`.

Comment: @Chariot como existen varias vías para sobrecargar operadores, los mismos no se tratan de la misma forma que las funciones miembro tradicionales. En consecuencia los errores que encuentras si los tipos no coinciden son diferentes